# Heat-treatment for protein expression

Tags: protein-expression, purification, heat

I want to express thermophilic protein in *E. coli* and the first step purification is to heat the crude protein. Since I don't know the optimum temperature to denature the contaminants, I plan to heat the protein in three different temperatures. I currently have 120 ml crude protein and I wonder, is it okay for me to divide the crude protein for each temperature? So, I will heat 40 ml crude protein for each temperature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In fact this is exactly what you would do if you wanted to perform the experiment to determine which condition is best. For these sorts of experiments you use one batch and split it amongst the experimental variables, so that you don't have to deal with inter-batch effects (e.g. different concentrations of protein).